# No puedo asignar un valor double a un datagrid, lo toma como int

Tags: c#, .net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static int contador_fila = 0;

private void btn_Colocar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Utilidades.ValidarFormulario(this,errorProvider1) == false)
    {
       bool existe = false;
       int num_fila =0;

      if (contador_fila == 0)
      {
          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt_CodigoProducto.Text, txt_Descripcion.Text, txt_Precio.Text, txt_Cantidad.Text);

          double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[contador_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[contador_fila].Cells[3].Value);

          dataGridView1.Rows[contador_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;

          contador_fila++;

      }
      else
      {
          foreach (DataGridViewRow Fila  in dataGridView1.Rows)
          {
              if (Fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString() ==txt_CodigoProducto.Text)
              {
                  existe = true;
                  num_fila = Fila.Index;
              }
          }

          if (existe == true)
          {   // le cambie el txt de cantidad a precio
              dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(txt_Cantidad.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value)).ToString();

              double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);

              dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;
          }
          else
          {
              dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt_CodigoProducto.Text, txt_Descripcion.Text, txt_Precio.Text, txt_Cantidad.Text);
              // movi la posicion de celda
             double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[contador_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[contador_fila].Cells[3].Value);

            dataGridView1.Rows[contador_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;

            contador_fila++;
          }
      }

  }
}
```

cuando lo asigno los 15.50 los toma como 1550:

[image: cuando lo asigno los 15.50 los toma como 1550]

Comment: Saludos prueba colocando el formato de la columna algo así: `dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N";`  O lo puedes hacer a través del diseñador en la edición de la columna en la propiedad `DefaultCellStyle` y colocas la N

Comment: Gracias bro, lo intenté pero no funciono, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías trabajar con cadenas (String), esto te facilitará darle un formato (Llamado máscara), donde puedes ingresar a este artículo de [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), para darle una máscara al tipo de dato: **double**.

Como por ejemplo:

```
public string ObtenerStringDeDouble(double valor)
{
    return value.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Formato 0.00
}
```

Ahora si deseas realizar una operación con los tipos doubles te recomiendo almacenar la información en un objeto (Como por ejemplo una matriz).

Saludos, espero  haberte ayudado.

Comment: soy muy nuevo en la programación y pues viendo unos tutoriales hice mi código, hice esto 
  dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToString (importe); pero no funciono, de igual manera gracias.